# Does the ket $\mid \psi \rangle$ and the ket $ \alpha \mid \psi \rangle$ represent the same state?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, interference, superposition, quantum-states

To show that the state spin $\frac{1}{2}$ particles get a minus sign under a $2\pi$ rotation the following experiment is made

[image]

A beam of neutron is divided in two beams $A$ and $B$. The beam $A$ follow a free path and beam $B$ passes troughs a magnetic field $B_0$. The state of a particle in beam $B$ suffer a phase change by $e^{\pm \omega T}$ where $T$ is the time that it stays in the magnetic field and $\omega=kB_0$ with $k$ some neutron dependent constant. Finally the two beams meets and we see interference.

Now according to quantum mechanics for a constant $\alpha$ a ket  $ \mid \psi \rangle$ and  a ket $\alpha \mid \psi \rangle$ represents the same state. Isn't this experiment a contradiction with this postulate?

Comment: Keyword: relative phase vs. overall phase

Comment: @Nihar Karve could you explain me why do you mean by that

Comment: Overall phase: $$\left|\psi\right\rangle \sim e^{i\alpha}\left|\psi\right\rangle $$. Relative phase: $$\left|\psi_{1}\right\rangle +\left|\psi_{2}\right\rangle \nsim\left|\psi_{1}\right\rangle +e^{i\alpha}\left|\psi_{2}\right\rangle $$.